# Estimate nearly-singular Gaussian covariance matrix

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, normal-distribution

Suppose I have $m$ samples drawn from a Gaussian in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and need sample covariance $\Sigma_m$ to be $\epsilon$-close to true covariance $\Sigma$:

$$E\|\Sigma_m-\Sigma\| \le \epsilon \|\Sigma\|$$

How many samples do I need?

My distribution is nearly singular, in sense that intrinsic dimension $r$ is much smaller than embedding dimension $n$ where

$$r=\frac{\text{tr}(\Sigma)}{\|\Sigma\|}$$

The term "intrinsic dimensions" comes from Tropp's [book](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.01571), Chapter 7.

I found the following sample-size requirement in [Vershynin, High-Dimensional Probability](https://www.math.uci.edu/%7Ervershyn/papers/HDP-book/HDP-book.pdf) Remark 5.6.3, for an *arbitrary* distribution:
$$m \approx \epsilon^{-2} r \log n$$

Can this be tightened for a Gaussian distribution? In particular, I'm wondering if the  $\log n$ factor can be dropped.

Here's what error looks like for various dimensions with intrinsic dimension fixed.
[image]

[notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/mathse-gaussian-sample-error.nb)

Comment: Are you estimating the covariance by the sample covariance, or a shrinkage-based estimator, or … ?

Comment: There's an issue of $m$ vs $m-1$ in denominator, but I think it won't affect the bound, so the standard definition of sample covariance works -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_mean_and_covariance#Definition_of_sample_covariance

Comment: I ask because it’s pretty well established that, in higher dimensions, the sample covariance tends to be a poor estimator of the actual covariance. Nothing to do with the choice of $m$ vs $m - 1$.

Comment: The question is specifically about sample covariance

Comment: An interesting question. The norm is the spectral norm?

Comment: Is the matrix $\Sigma_m$ defined as 
$$\Sigma_m = \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m \Sigma_k$$
And what is the norm used here?

Comment: operator norm (spectral norm), yes on sample covariance (ie, MLE estimate of covariance from sample). Can assume 0 mean, don't think this affects analysis

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I added a simulation in an answer. If we grow dimensions while keeping intrinsic dimensionality fixed, and sample size fixed, the error doesn't seem to grow with dimensionality

Comment: reposted on Mathoverflow -- https://mathoverflow.net/questions/395098/dimension-free-sample-complexity-for-estimating-gaussian-covariance

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer looks like I didn't read Vershynin carefully enough, it's [Theorem 9.2.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coQrg.png)